# when I select a data from a dropdown list and insert into a table then the status of the inserted data should update in same table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

When I select an option from a drop down list and insert into a table then the status of the inserted data should be updated in same table. I statically add some data in table called `room_numbers`. They are
id, room numbers and status.

**room_numbers table**

```
id rooms status
1  101   1
2  102   1
3  103   1
```

**bookroom.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select id="rooms" name="rooms" value="{{ old('rooms') }}">
        <option></option>
        @foreach($roomnumber_array as $data)
            <option value="{{$data->rooms}}">{{$data->rooms}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>                        
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="from" class="col-md-4 col-form-label >{{ __('From') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="from" type="date" name="from" value="{{ old('from') }}" autocomplete="from">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="to" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">{{ __('To') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="to" type="date" name="to" value="{{ old('to') }}" autocomplete="to">
    </div>
</div>
```

here I fetch room numbers from `room_numbers` table and insert from date and to date 
into the **room_book** table. When a user inserts room, the status of appropriate room will be  updated as 0. 
now the `room_numbers` table will be

```
id rooms status
1  101   0
2  102   1
3  103   1
```

how can be I achieve this? please help me.

Comment: please post your logic and your form action

Comment: Show your controller code

Comment: In the store function set status=0 when a user insert the dates, thats all